# Count occurence of key per column in many columns in csv

Tags: python, csv

Have a csv like this

```
col1,col2,col3
t,t,t
f,f,f
t,f,t
```

The the file is quite big (50 Mb) with many columns

Need to count the amount of t per column

Tried this:

```
import csv
import collections

col1 = collections.Counter()
with open('file.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=','):
        col1[row[0]] += 1

print 'Number of t in col1: %s' % col1['t']
```

But this only counts the first column (col1), how do I count many columns?

Comment: How does your code check if the first column is "t"?

Comment: Another loop on columns inside the first one and col1[column_index] +=1

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Need a code that will work for n amount of columns. At Rory Daulton I use col1['t'] ... @Benjamin Hmmm ... dont really understand what you mean? Can you elaborate some more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv
totals = {}

with open('file.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=','):
        for column, cell in enumerate(row):
            if column not in totals:
                totals[column] = 0
            if cell == 't':
                totals[column] += 1

for column in totals:
    print 'column %d has %d trues' % (column, totals[column])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will count the number of Ts in the first column.  I make the assumption that they will all be lowercase, but if this is not true you can easily make that change.

```
t_count = []
with open('file.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        for col_num, col in enumerate(line.rstrip().split(',')):
            if len(t_count) < col_num + 1:
                t_count.append(0)
            if col == "t":
                t_count[col_num] += 1
print t_coun
```

t

> [2, 1, 2]

This will tell the number of Ts per column, so index 0 is col1 and so on...

Comment: Thanks!!! Was looking for a more automated way to count for a value in n amount of columns. With your code I need to create "if" for each column and a var for amount of t per column.